# Webdriverio cucumber cant use promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, gherkin, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I m trying to learn a bit more cucumberjs with webdriverIO and I m having some troubles while launching my tests.

Actually, I want to cover this simple feature :

```
Feature: Example Feature
  In order to become productive
  As a test automation engineer
  I want to understand the basics of cucumber

  Scenario: My First Test Scenario
    Given I have open "https://google.com"
    Then the title should be "Google".
    And the bar should be empty.
```

With this test :

```
const assert = require('assert');
module.exports = function() {
    this.Given(/^I have open "([^"]*)"$/, function(arg1, callback) {
      browser
        .url(arg1)
        .call(callback);
    });

    this.Then(/^the title should be "([^"]*)"\.$/, function(arg1, callback) {
      // First solution
      const title = browser.getTitle();
      assert(title, arg1);

      // Second solution
      browser
        .getTitle()
        .then(title2 => {
          assert(title2, arg1);
          callback();
        });
    });

    this.Then(/^the bar should be empty\.$/, function(callback) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        callback(null, 'pending');
    });
}
```

**My configuration file :**

```
"use strict";

const WebDriverIO = require('webdriverio');
const browser = WebDriverIO.remote({
  baseUrl: 'https://google.com', // Or other url, e.g. localhost:3000
  host: 'localhost', // Or any other IP for Selenium Standalone
  port: 4444,
  waitforTimeout: 120 * 1000,
  logLevel: 'silent',
  screenshotPath: `${__dirname}/documentation/screenshots/`,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: process.env.SELENIUM_BROWSER || 'chrome',
  },
});

global.browser = browser;

module.exports = function() {
  this.registerHandler('BeforeFeatures', function(event, done) {
    browser.init().call(done);
  });

  this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function(event, done) {
    browser.end().call(done);
  });
};
```

**My problem**

My problems are :

- I never pass in the *.call(callback)* function
- If I bypass the previous point by adding callback() just after *.url(arg1)* , I pass to the next point
- In the first *Then*, neither the first solution nor the second solution seems to work. While I m trying to log the *const title* value, I have a pending promise. But when I try to resolve that promise (second case) I never log nothing (even in the rejecting case).

**Constraints**

- I don't want to use wdio
- I m using selenium 2.53
- I m using cucumberjs 1.3.1
- I m using webdriverio 4.4.0
- I m using Nodejs v4.6.0

EDIT : I m always having timeout issues

Answer (score 0):

Use [chimpjs](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp). It integrates webdriverio, cucumber, and other friends. It's "on fiber", so you can write your tests mostly in a synchronous style. I use it and when I have to use promises I can or need to.